CROSS-JOIN not all rows in result
I am a beginner and I have this problem. I have two tables:

date table
a data table

I want to join all the rows from the first table with all the rows of the 2nd table ie cross join. After writing the code, unfortunately it does not show me all the date rows ie: 500 rows with the date 2024-06-24 and it jumps to 2024-07-02. what is the problem?
My query:
    select
    *
    from dates as dt, tab2 as po
    WHERE 1=1 
        AND dt."Date" >= getdate()
        AND dt."Date" <= dateadd(day,60,getdate())


It jumps? Maybe you want to add an ORDER BY clause in order to get your result rows sorted by date?

You shouldn't use comma joins by the way. This is an outdated syntax of the 1980s. If you want a cross join, say cross join: FROM dates as dt CROSS JOIN tab2 as po.

And please always tag your SQL requests with your DBMS. Is this Microsoft SQL Server?

I think the missing order by is the problem. Also note that 1 = 1 serves no purpose here.

Order by would solve the problem - thanks.
Note 1 = 1 is for my debuging.
